# Asymtotic bound for recurrence of $T(n)=2T(n/2)+ \sum_{i=0}^{n} (i+2)^2$ using substitution

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics

What can be an initial guess for finding the tight asymptotic bounds of $T(n)=2T(n/2)+ \sum_{i=0}^{n} (i+2)^2$ using substitution method?

Comment: You can find the answer using the master theorem.

Comment: Hint, expand the sum on the right to get a closed form for $T(n)$. You can use the formula $\sum_{i = 0}^{n}i^2 = \frac{n (n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$.